# Getting empty data when I'm passing value to an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm just wondering on how I got an empty object, and how to fix it.

tax1 has 16 objects

Payroll controller

```
if (vm.period === 'Semi-Monthly') {
      for (var x = 0; x < vm.tax1.length; x++) {
        if (vm.tax1[x].eventType === 'sm') {
          vm.tax2[x] = vm.tax1[x];
        }
      }
    } else if( vm.period === 'Monthly'){
      for (var y = 0; y < vm.tax1.length; y++) {
        if (vm.tax1[y].eventType === 'm') {
          vm.tax2[y] = vm.tax1[y];
        }
      }
    }
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Please add actual code instead of image.

Comment: this is because you are using same index x or y. Say if in your iteration there is match found for the condition if (vm.tax1[x].eventType === 'sm') when x >= 8 then vm.tax2[x] will add first entry at 8th position and first 7 will go empty. Similar is case of y.

Comment: @Harpreet hey man thanks for the explanation, after drinking coffee i know the fix by creating another var to start to 0 and put it inside tax2[ var 0 here ]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Silly mistake from my side..

here's the fix

```
var x = 0;
var y = 0;

    if (vm.period === 'Semi-Monthly') {
      for ( x = 0; x < vm.tax1.length; x++) {
        if (vm.tax1[x].eventType === 'sm') {
          vm.tax2[y] = vm.tax1[x];
          y++;
        }
      }
    } else if( vm.period === 'Monthly'){
      for ( x = 0; x < vm.tax1.length; x++) {
        if (vm.tax1[x].eventType === 'm') {
          vm.tax2[y] = vm.tax1[x];
          y++;
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Indices are difficult to read and error-prone, you can consider using `.push` or `.filter`

Using `.push`

```
vm.tax2 = [];
var eventType;

if (vm.period == 'Semi-Monthly') {
  eventType = 'sm';
}
else if( vm.period == 'Monthly') {
  eventType = 'm';
}

vm.tax1.forEach(function(item) {
  if (item.eventType == eventType) {
    vm.tax2.push(item);
  }
});
```

Using `.filter`

```
var eventType;

if (vm.period == 'Semi-Monthly') {
  eventType = 'sm';
}
else if( vm.period == 'Monthly') {
  eventType = 'm';
}

vm.tax2 = vm.tax1.filter(function(item) {
  return (item.eventType == eventType);
});
```